# write and read to a USB port using the command line

Tags: bash, usb

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 system connected to and embedded controller board via USB. The board is a USB device.
I can enumerate the board with the Ubuntu system. It shows up with command `lsusb`.
To debug my firmware on the board I would like to send data to the board via USB and read data from the board via USB. The USB has 2 BULK endpoints. EP0 used for commands. EP1 OUT used to send data from host and EP1 IN used for host to receive data.

Are there bash commands to:

- send data to the EP0 OUT?
- send data to the EP1 OUT and read data from EP1 IN?

The command `lsusb` gives the port number, VID and PID.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please take a look [here](https://github.com/obdev/v-usb/tree/master/examples/usbtool). I haven't used it ever, but it may help you. I can't offer a quality answer because I'm not familiar with the USB internals, though I understand your question.